# How to run VBA code in excel for each sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need a help. with this code:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets
        If ws.Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
            Select Case Target.Value
            Case Is <> ""
                Me.Tab.Color = vbGreen
            Case ""
                Me.Tab.Color = vbWhite
            Case Else
                Me.Tab.Color = vbBlue
            End Select
        End If
    End Sub
```

It is not working, but I don't know why. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this `Book1.xlsm` another open workbook away from ThisWorkbook?

Comment: Have you got two workbooks .. One for the code and the other is `Book1.xlsm`?

Comment: No, i have one workbook

Answer (score 2):

In ThisWorkbook module put the code like that

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        Select Case Target.Value
            Case Is <> ""
                Sh.Tab.Color = vbGreen
            Case ""
                Sh.Tab.Color = vbWhite
            Case Else
                'This will not happen as it is either empty or non-empty
                Sh.Tab.Color = vbBlue
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Svetlozar Lazarov: We here, when somebody answer our question solving our problem, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **actepted answer**. Please, do it! In this way, somebody else searching for something similar will know that the code works...